# Query custom dimensions on the sessions AND the hit level

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

The `customDimensions` with index `6` corresponds to a UUID both on the session and the hit levels.

On the session level I can use the following standard SQL query to retrieve the UUID:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION customDimensionByIndex(indx INT64, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>) AS (
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE indx=x.index)
);

SELECT
customDimensionByIndex(6, customDimensions) AS session_uuid -- Customer UUID
FROM `94860076.ga_sessions_20170822`
limit 10
```

Similarly, on the hits level I can use:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION customDimensionByIndex(indx INT64, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>) AS (
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE indx=x.index)
);

SELECT
customDimensionByIndex(6, hits.customDimensions) AS hit_uuid -- Customer UUID
FROM `94860076.ga_sessions_20170822`, unnest(hits) as hits
limit 10
```

However, I fail to use both in the same query. For example, I want to have a results set where each row corresponds to a *session* and the columns are `session_uuid` and `array_of_hit_uuids`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION customDimensionByIndex(indx INT64, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>) AS (
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE indx=x.index)
);
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT
    customDimensionByIndex(6, customDimensions) AS session_uuid,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT val FROM (
        SELECT customDimensionByIndex(6, hits.customDimensions) AS val
        FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hits
      )
      WHERE NOT val IS NULL
    ) AS hit_uuid
  FROM `94860076.ga_sessions_20170822`
)
WHERE session_uuid IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 10
```

You can test it with public dataset

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION customDimensionByIndex(indx INT64, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>) AS (
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE indx=x.index)
);
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT
    customDimensionByIndex(2, customDimensions) AS session_uuid,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT val FROM (
        SELECT customDimensionByIndex(1, hits.customDimensions) AS val
        FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hits
      )
      WHERE NOT val IS NULL
    ) AS hit_uuid
  FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
)
WHERE session_uuid IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Wouldn't an inner join be faster?

Comment: most likely not - but you can try :) meantime, have you tried above? did it work for you?

Comment: It seems to do the trick, but eventually, I used a different approach. The array generated by your approach was not what I wanted. Your approach yields a session-centric view where the hits are mapped to arrays. Right?